# How can I use a ref to switch between two buttons in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I'm creating a stopwatch app. The stop watch works when I click the start and stop buttons, but as soon as I hit the spacebar it restarts at 0 and starts to speed up the stopwatch.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {milliSecondsElapsed: 0};
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
        this.textInput = React.createRef();
    }
    textInput = () => {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    updateState(e) {
        this.setState({milliSecondsElapsed: e.target.milliSecondsElapsed })
    }
    ...
    keyPress = (e) => {
        // spacebar
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            handleStop();
        }
    }
    ...
    handleStart = () => {
        this.setState({
            milliSecondsElapsed: (0)
        });
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                milliSecondsElapsed: (this.state.milliSecondsElapsed + 1)
            });
        }, 10)
    }
    handleStop = () => {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
    render() {
        return (    
            <div className="index">
                <input value = {this.state.milliSecondsElapsed} onChange = {this.updateState} ref={this.textInput}/>
                <button onClick = {this.handleStart}>START</button>
                <button onClick = {this.handleStop}>STOP</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

I've tried some things with refs but none of it has to led to it doing what I want it to. Basically, I want to hit the spacebar to start the stopwatch and then press it again to stop the stopwatch. I want to have the focus be on the start button when I load the page and the stop button after the stopwatch is started.

Answer (score 1):

In programming using React, always assess if the task can be done without using refs.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.

You don't really refs in this scenario, just have a event listener on the window that detects a key press. Clean as necessary when the component unmounts. You can implement some logic on the keyPress function to assess whether the timer should stop or start.

```
this.state = { 
  milliSecondsElapsed: 0,
  timerInProgress: false // state to detect whether timer has started
};

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", this.keyPress);
}

keyPress = (e) => {
    // some logic to assess stop/start of timer
    if (this.state.milliSecondsElapsed === 0) {
        this.handleStart();
    } else if (this.state.timerInProgress === false) {
        this.handleStart();
    } else {
        this.handleStop();
    }
};

<button onClick={this.handleStart} ref={(ref) => (this.startBtn = ref)}>
    START
</button>
<button onClick={this.handleStop} ref={(ref) => (this.startBtn = ref)}>
    STOP
</button>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bush-nzg76?file=/src/App.js

---

To be answer complete though, you can use the same logic above using refs by simply attaching a ref to each button.

```
keyPress = (e) => {
  // some logic to assess stop/start of timer
  if (this.state.milliSecondsElapsed === 0) {
    this.startBtn.click();
  } else if (this.state.timerInProgress === false) {
    this.startBtn.click();
  } else {
    this.stopBtn.click();
  }
};

<button onClick={this.handleStart} ref={(ref) => (this.startBtn = ref)}>
  START
</button>
<button onClick={this.handleStop} ref={(ref) => (this.stopBtn = ref)}>
  STOP
</button>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-chaum-zcfl6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have implemented what you used with componentDidMount in the first example. It seems it is still focused on the start button, as the same thing is happening. When I hit the spacebar, the timer starts but when I press it again, it starts again twice as fast rather than stop.

Comment: i suggest you prevent the default of the `mousedown` event. `<button onMouseDown={e=>e.preventDefault()} onClick={this.handleStart}>START</button>`

Answer (score 0):

To specifically "switch" focuses of the buttons, you can opt to assign a `ref` on each button then invoke the opposite button's [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus) event when the "start" and "stop" timer handlers are invoked and the new state is set.

```
this.state = { 
  milliSecondsElapsed: 0,
  timerInProgress: false // state to detect whether timer has started
};

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", this.keyPress);
}

keyPress = (e) => {
  // some logic to assess stop/start of timer
  if (this.state.milliSecondsElapsed === 0) {
    this.startBtn.click();
  } else if (this.state.timerInProgress === false) {
    this.startBtn.click();
  } else {
    this.stopBtn.click();
  }
};

handleStart = () => {
  if (this.state.timerInProgress === true) return;

  this.setState({
    milliSecondsElapsed: 0
  });
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(
      {
        milliSecondsElapsed: this.state.milliSecondsElapsed + 1,
        timerInProgress: true
      },
      () => {
        this.stopBtn.focus(); /* switch focus to STOP button */
      }
    );
  }, 10);
};
handleStop = () => {
  this.setState(
    {
      timerInProgress: false
    },
    () => {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      this.startBtn.focus(); /* switch focus to START button */
    }
  );
};

<button onClick={this.handleStart} ref={(ref) => (this.startBtn = ref)}>
  START
</button>
<button onClick={this.handleStop} ref={(ref) => (this.stopBtn = ref)}>
  STOP
</button>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-liskov-fgbid?file=/src/App.js